# Update LaTeX document content with the parameter values of a Matlab model

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab model with some parameters ( a=1, b=2, c=3, etc). I want this values to appear "automatically" in my LaTeX document and when they are changed in the Matlab code they are in the LaTeX document also.

I imagined something like storing the Matlab parameters values in a text file which is then used by the LaTeX document to be incorporated in the text or in a table. Updating the Matlab parameter values, running the code to update the value text file, and compiling the LaTeX document should then allow to have the values up to date in the LaTeX document.

I am pretty sure I am not the first one with this kind of question but I could not find the right keywords to get a solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Depending on the output you can get matlab to produce this can be extremely easy (if Matlab can output a file reading, say `\newcommand*{\parama}{1}\newcommand*{\paramb}{2}`, ... you just need to `\input` that file) to more complicated (when matlab produces a `.csv` file, which could be read with `csvsimple` or `datatool`).

Comment: You are right it is dramatically easy. Yes I can generate almost everything with matlab with any extension here .tex.  Thank you!!

Comment: Great! If you have a working solution it would be nice if you could write up a quick answer so other people with a similar problem can benefit from this post.

Comment: Yes I will generate a basic example to show how to do it and post it here by answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to moewe, here the solution to my problem:

The Matlab code example:

```
clear all
close all
clc


%Parameters
a=3;
b=-2;
c=3;

% Model
y=a^3+2*b^2+c

%% Tex file writing

str = strcat(['\newcommand*{\parama}{',num2str(a),'}','\newcommand*{\paramb}{',num2str(b),'}','\newcommand*{\paramc}{',num2str(c),'}','\newcommand*{\paramy}{',num2str(y),'}']);

% To escape the backslashes and percent signs:
str = strrep(str,'\','\\');
str = strrep(str,'%','%%');
fileID = fopen('parameters.tex','w');

%Export values to use in LateX 
fprintf(fileID,str);
```

This code produces the LaTeX file parameters.tex with the currently used parameter values.

The minimal LaTeX example using the parameter values:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\input{parameters.tex}

\begin{document}

The Matlab model uses $a=\parama$, $b=\paramb$ and $c=\paramc$ to calculate $y=a^3+2b^2+c=\paramy$

\end{document}
```

Which produces in LaTeX:

[image: Example output]

A similar example I just found trying to deal in Matlab with the special character used in LaTeX (\, %, etc) is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523555/write-string-as-it-is-to-a-file-in-matlab